# bulk_create() of two linked tables on SQLite using peewee : primary key not updated

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I have two tables with a 1-n relationship and I would like to insert data in these tables using `bulk_create()`.

Let's take the [User and Tweet example](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#models-and-fields).

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('my_app.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField(unique=True)

class Tweet(BaseModel):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='tweets')
    message = TextField()
```

I would like to create unsaved instances of `User` and `Tweet` and to load them with `bulk_create()`. A naive solution would be:

```
db.create_tables([User, Tweet])

john = User(username='John')
mehdi = User(username='Mehdi')
users = [john, mehdi]

tweets = [Tweet(user=john, message='Hello twitter world!'),
          Tweet(user=mehdi, message='This is my first message.'),
          Tweet(user=mehdi, message='This is my second message.')]

User.bulk_create(users)
Tweet.bulk_create(tweets)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work because the `User` instances primary keys are not updated ([as stated in the documentation except for Postgres databases](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.bulk_create)).

As it seems impossible to update the primary key of the `User` instances (even if it were possible, it would probably be very inefficient to read the primary keys from the database), the only solution I can see is to use my own primary key and set it when creating the instance. This would mean not using the very convenient auto-incrementing primary key system of peewee and I would like too know if there is any alternative before to go that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came out with. I would have preferred to avoid messing with peewee's internals but it works fine.

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('my_app.db')


class BaseModel(Model):
    id_counter = 0
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True, constraints=[SQL('AUTOINCREMENT')])

    def _set_id(self):
        if self.id is None:
            self.id = self.__class__.id_counter
            self.__class__.id_counter += 1

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def bulk_create(cls, model_list, batch_size=None):
        max_id = cls.select(fn.MAX(cls.id)).scalar() or 0
        cls.id_counter = max_id + 1
        for model in model_list:
            model._set_id()
            model._update_fks()
        return super(BaseModel, cls).bulk_create(model_list=model_list, batch_size=batch_size)

    def _update_fks(self):
        for field_name, field in self._meta.fields.items():
            if isinstance(field, ForeignKeyField):
                fk_field_name = field_name + '_id'
                fk_id = getattr(self, field_name).id
                setattr(self, fk_field_name, fk_id)

    class Meta:
        database = db


class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField(unique=True)


class Tweet(BaseModel):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='tweets', field='id')
    message = TextField()


db.create_tables([User, Tweet])

# Creating users and tweets one by one
sarah = User.create(username='Sarah')
Tweet.create(user=sarah, message='First tweet in history')

# Bulk user and tweet insertion
john = User(username='John')
mehdi = User(username='Mehdi')
users = [john, mehdi]

tweets = [Tweet(user=john, message='Hello twitter world!'),
          Tweet(user=mehdi, message='This is my first message.'),
          Tweet(user=mehdi, message='This is my second message.')]

User.bulk_create(users)
Tweet.bulk_create(tweets)

# Creating users and tweets one by one after bulk insertion
miranda = User.create(username='Miranda')

Tweet.create(user=miranda, message='The last tweet')
```